# How to solve problem "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mac"

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

First I did pip3 install pymouse, then in the file (let's call it file1): import pymouse

running the code (Python 3 file1.py), and the error "Module Not Found Error: No module named 'mac'" crashes

At the same time, everything was fine earlier, but after I installed homeBrew, such errors began

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution - "brew install python"

Answer (score 0):

You can install Python3 with pyenv:

1. brew install pyenv
2. pyenv install <python_version> 
   For example:
   ** pyenv install 3.10.7

To set the newly installed version as the default 
3) pyenv global <python_version>